# avconv or FFMPEG command to have multiple pictures slices from a direct webcam on pc

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I have found the command

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.2.69.201:554/ch0_0.h264 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/120 img%03d.jpg
```

but it fail if I'm not on network. I tryed on my on computer but I have bind error.
I would like to have a command like or a mix of these one:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mpg
```

Thanks for your help. This is appreciated if that possible

Comment: So what exactly are you using? `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg, the fake "`ffmpeg`" from Libav, or `avconv` (also from Libav). You should show the complete console output from each command.

Answer (score 0):

Ok all I found it after a lot of work. This meaned reading the error message. That's the key and you always mention it:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -bt 20M -vf fps=1 img%03d.jpg
```

This code work simply and perfectly. I hope you enjoy.
Thanks all